# apt command when installing to check, make sure every dependency does really exist

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

How is the command for `apt` when installing to check, make sure every dependency **really exists** recursively?

Some past disaster remove many `/usr/bin` binaries just to be skipped and overlooked by `apt` which innocently confirm installation is perfect.

Please how to have it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dpkg -V
```

will look at all installed packages and report any missing or modified files. You can use this to build a list of missing binaries; `dpkg -S` will then allow you to determine which packages provide these binaries, and then

```
apt reinstall ...
```

will allow you to reinstall all the packages which aren’t complete.

This should do the trick:

```
dpkg -S $(dpkg -V | awk '/\/bin\// { print $2 }' | sort -u) |
awk -F: '{ print $1 }' |
sort -u |
xargs sudo apt reinstall
```

If you don’t want to check the changes before confirming them, add `-y` to the `apt` command (`... apt reinstall -y`).